# How can I apply a utility function to a supertype's parameter of a generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm not even sure I wrote the question correctly, so  take it with a grain of salt. I would like to know wow do I apply an Omit<> function to the parameterized value of a generic type?

I want this to give me a compiler error because tag shouldn't be supported

```
<ModalBody tag={'bjaisd'}></ModalBody>
```

Here's my module type code

```
declare module 'shards-react' {

  class BaseShardsComponent<T> extends React.Component<{
    className?: string,
    tag?: string | keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap,
  } & T> {}

  export class ModalBody extends BaseShardsComponent {}
}
```

Somehow in the ModalBody implementation I want to be able to reach into the parameterized value defined as

```
{
  className?: string,
  tag?: string | keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap,
} & T
```

And wrap that whole union in an `Omit<type, 'tag'>` but I have no idea what the syntax might be, or if it's even possible. Also I don't want to effect any of the other implementations extending from BaseShardsComponent. This is a special case.

Comment: Can you tell what is the purpose of omit, what do you want to achieve here?

Comment: I'm trying to remove an attribute from a jsx element because it's not supported

Answer (score 0):

Would this work in your use case:

```
import React from 'React';

module 'shards-react' {
    type Props = {
        className?: string,
        tag?: string | keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap,
    };
    class BaseShardsComponent<T> extends React.Component<Props & T> {}

    export class ModalBody<T> extends BaseShardsComponent<Omit<Props, 'tag'> & T> {}
}
```

?

Though if we're allowed to change Props, I'd rather do:

```
import React from 'React';

module 'shards-react' {
    type ModalBodyProps = {
        className?: string,
    };

    type BaseShardsComponentProps = ModalBodyProps & {
        tag?: string | keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap,
    }

    class BaseShardsComponent<T> extends React.Component<BaseShardsComponentProps & T> {}

    export class ModalBody<T> extends BaseShardsComponent<ModalBodyProps & T> {}
}
```

If you really can't change `BaseShardsComponentProps`, then maybe this:

```
import React from 'React';

module 'shards-react' {
    class BaseShardsComponent<T> extends React.Component<{
        className?: string,
        tag?: string | keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap,
    } & T> { }

    type BaseShardsProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof BaseShardsComponent>

    export class ModalBody<T> extends BaseShardsComponent<Omit<BaseShardsProps, 'tag'> & T> {}
}
```